How to send application trace data to OpenTelemetry in Kubernetes?
I installed opentelemery collector
helm repo add open-telemetry https://open-telemetry.github.io/opentelemetry-helm-charts
helm install opentelemetry-collector open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector --set mode=deployment --set image.repository="otel/opentelemetry-collector-k8s" --set command.name="otelcol-k8s" -f values.yaml

values.yaml
mode: deployment

config:
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
        http:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
  exporters:
    otlp:
      endpoint: jaeger-collector.default.svc.cluster.local:14250
      tls:
        insecure: true
    debug:
      verbosity: detailed
  service:
    pipelines:
      traces:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [otlp]
      metrics:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [debug]
      logs:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [debug]

Also installed Jaeger
helm repo add jaegertracing https://jaegertracing.github.io/helm-charts
helm install jaeger jaegertracing/jaeger

Port forward
kubectl port-forward svc/opentelemetry-collector 4317:4317
kubectl port-forward svc/opentelemetry-collector 4318:4318

Run an application to point to the port
/*instrumentation.ts*/
import * as opentelemetry from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc';
import { PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';

const resource = new Resource({
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'test-service',
});

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: 'http://localhost:4317',
    // optional - collection of custom headers to be sent with each request, empty by default
    headers: {},
  }),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter({
      url: 'http://localhost:4317',
      headers: {}, // an optional object containing custom headers to be sent with each request
    }),
  }),
  resource: resource,
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});
sdk.start();

After access the app several times, the opentelemetry-collector pod got error log:
2024-07-19T08:50:13.705Z    error   exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:90   Exporting failed. Dropping data.    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "otlp", "error": "not retryable error: Permanent error: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.TraceService", "dropped_items": 2}
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
    go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.104.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:90
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
    go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.104.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
    go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.104.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43

The log in jaeger-collector pod:
{"level":"info","ts":1721717166.6132424,"caller":"grpc@v1.60.0/server.go:983","msg":"[core][Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \\\"GET / HTTP/1.1\\\\r\\\\nHost: lo\\\"\"","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}

How to setup correctly?

might not be anything, but the host for the gRPC request is Host: lo, check to see if that resolves as this could be as simple as a name resolution issue.

@RichardSlater Thank you. The issue due to didn't install cert-manager for jaeger.

Thanks for letting me know, if you are able to answer your own question below it would help future users searching for the same problem.

The issue was due to the cert-manager. After I install this way, it works:
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.15.1/cert-manager.yaml
kubectl create namespace observability
kubectl create -f https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/releases/download/v1.57.0/jaeger-operator.yaml -n observability

